# I have an issue with my Codeigniter project when I upload to my host

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using for the first time Codeigniter, and I have some issue with my views (subpages) when I upload it to my host. My homepage works fine, but the browser can not find my views.

**I get this error:**

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /Projects/greenpeace was not found on this server.

On my local server, everything works fine.

[image]

Comment: Have you change `base_url`?

Comment: i think you don't have an the htaccess file ? in your project root dir.

Comment: @B.Desai yes I have changed it, and the homepage works, but not the subpages

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar  I have the htaccess file in the applicaiton folder as well, I have uploaded a photo about the libraries you can see it there. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do following things.

1) Rewrite module should be enabled on your server.

2) Remove index.php from config file -

path - application->config->config.php

**use this -**  `$config['index_page'] = '';`

**instead of -** `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

3) Put .htaccess file in root directory -

Htaccess Code -- (filename should be .htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It will work 100%, please let me know if you have any issues.